# showing dynamic controller view in landsacape orientation?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I created different UIViewControllers and made their view using nib file . I only want to show in landscape view all these controllers. This thing works fine with these controller.

I created 1 controller dynamically and made view dynamically using.

```
UIViewController* temp=[[UIViewController alloc] init ];
temp.view=overlayview;//overlayviw was created dyanmcailly
```

Now how can i show this view in landscape it always open in portrait view 
is there any way like
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method can be defined for dynamic controller .

As all my controller classes with nib files have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation implmented and that let me to show view in landscape view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it's it better to a create some kind of base view controller with constructor accepting the view as parameter and proper implementation of the methods you need. Even if you need it to be more dynamic you can also have some configuration properties to your base view controller. Otherwise it's possible to add methods though the obj-c runtime, but that's totally unnecessarily.